# How can I better organize my code in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I'm doing a project in Laravel, the view has already become so many `@foreach` and `@if` nested inside each other that I'm already confused which one closes (yes, I should have commented).

How now to find out what belongs to what, without raking it all over again? I am coding in PhpStorm.

Comment: Use subviews. Use components

Comment: For goodness sake, use proper indentation. PhpStorm has a command that will do that, and has code folding to make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

One Place is [Laracast](https://laracasts.com). It's specially built for Laravel Devs. I can suggest you few good tutorials. One is [Ten Techniques for Cleaner Code](http://%5Bhttps://laracasts.com/series/ten-techniques-for-cleaner-code) another is [whipping monstrous code into shape](https://laracasts.com/series/whip-monstrous-code-into-shape) & for cherry on top you can always read some [Design patterns tutorials](https://laracasts.com/series/design-patterns-in-php).